# Java regex multiple tags and attributes

Tags: java, xml, regex, tags

This is how my xml looks like

```
<xml>
    <tagA value="one"/>
    <tagB value="two"/>
    <tagA value="three"/>
    <tagC value="null"/>
</xml>
```

I **only** have access to `String.split(regex)` thru this simplified API layer above Java  that **I have to use** (No Pattern). 
The closest I have come to parse out all the tags:

```
String xmlContent = "<xml><tagA value=\"one\"/><tagB value=\"two\"/><tagA value=\"three\"/><tagC value=\"null\"/></xml>";
String[] splitedTexts = xmlContent.split("(?=<)(?<=>)");
for (String string : splitedTexts) {            
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

The result will be:

```
<xml>
<tagA value="one"/>
<tagB value="two"/>
<tagA value="three"/>
<tagC value="null"/>
</xml>
```

I'm just interested in tagA and tagB `(tagA|tagB)` but as soon as I try to add that I end up messing the regexp up. With JavaScript syntax it worked with this regex `<(tagA|tagB) value([\S]*)\b(\s*?=\s*?")\S*\B`.
Have not gotten that to work with Java. Expected output would be:

```
<tagA value="one"/>
<tagB value="two"/>
<tagA value="three"/>
```

The next step is to get the values in pair into a map

```
{"tagA", "one"}
{"tagB", "two"}
{"tagA", "three"}
```

Comment: "You must cut down the mightiest tree in the forest wiiiith... *a herring!*". In other words, regex is not the appropriate tool for the task: why do you have the restriction that you can *only* use it and not the proper tools (like a parser)? See also: [further reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: In this project we have to use a language that is a subset of Java, basically it is limited to a handfull of the String functions like `indexOf(regexp) subString() split(regex) matches(regexp) startsWith()`

Answer (score 1):

How about this expression that could be used instead of spliting:

**[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cX1fC7)**

```
/(?<=<)(\w+)\b(?!>)|(?<=value=")(\w+)/g
```

Comment: Looks nice but does not compile with Java. "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \
 \ )"

Comment: escaping characters is not part of the RegEx syntax you do that based on the language of implementation. In the above example it will be all the \ characters to implement it in Java

Comment: I have escaped the characters like this `(?<=<)(\\w+)\b(?!>)|(?<=value=\")(\\w+)` now I get the following result: `<xml><tagA value="
"/><tagB value="
"/><tagA value="
"/></xml>`

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations: you have discovered that regular expressions can't be used to parse XML. If you read some computer science theory, you will learn that this is because XML is not a regular language (its grammar - like other hierarchic formats such as JSON - is recursive).

So do it right: use an XML parser.

Comment: This answer was not very useful since I don't have access to a XML parser in this environment. Otherwise I would of course have done that.

Comment: If someone is asking you to process XML using an environment that does not provide an XML parser then you need to have a serious discussion with them.